# Is it possible to pass an executable to an MS-DOS program?

Tags: command-prompt

Is it possible to pass an `ELF 32-bit LSB executable(a.exe), version 1 (SYSV)` to a `MS-DOS executable (EXE) (b.exe), OS/2 or MS Windows`  as an argument? The reverse also?

Comment: What do you mean, "pass the executable"? What do you plan to do with it?

Comment: You should explain the problem you're having a bit better, perhaps provide a code example. The information you've provided is ambiguous.

Comment: When? Why? To whom? And please edit title of your question to be more descriptive

Comment: i hav an executable ,which is a simulator. I have built my application into executable form.I want pass this excuatable (my appln) to the simulator so that it will be executed..this is happening in all IDE simulators r8? I am interested in command line.. thats y..

Comment: You still really need to provide more information.  What is the simulator?  Does it expect to be given a parameter on the command line?  You can't just pass something to a random program and expect it to work - who wrote the simulator?

Comment: Dude, OS/2?  Come on.  This has to be a fake question.

Comment: Dude, Be a bit more wider and clear while asking questions. Explain the scenario well so that the readers can help you very well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the command line and (assuming you want to pass the path to 'a.exe') type "a.exe /?"

Does it come up with instructions on how to pass 'b.exe' to it?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than pass the executable, you could pass the path to the executable?

Comment: This is the answer. If you're having trouble with passing the path on the com mand line, you should show the code you used and what problem you had. I've done simulators before, and this is how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to pass in the exe via the command line, the closest you could come to would be to pipe it in, but you would have to do a setmode on stdin to binary. But the better solution would be to pass in a path to the exe to your emulation loader, have it load the exe and pass the data by buffer/pointer/reference to the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is possible using wine, on Linux.